# not able to insert data in my database through signup form in php

Tags: php, mysql

i am new to php so could someone help me. i am trying to insert data into my database through a signup form. but i dont know why my query is not working can someone point out where am i making mistake. here is the code

```
$a=$_POST['txt'];
    $b=$_POST['txt1'];
    $c=md5($_POST['pass']);
    $d=md5($_POST['pass1']);
    $f=1;
     $com_code = md5(uniqid(rand()));
    if($_POST['usertype']=='individual')
    {$e=1;
        }
        else if ($_POST['usertype']=='professional')
        {

            $e=2;}
$query="INSERT into user (user_name,user_email,user_password,user_retype_password,user_active,terms_services,unique_code) values ('$a','$b','$c','$d','0','$f','$com_code')";
            $holder1=mysql_query($query,$db_connect) or die ("cannot execute query");
                    if($holder1)
                    {
                        $last_inserted_mysql_id = mysql_insert_id();
                        }
                        $add_to_enrole="INSERT into user_enrole(user_id,user_type_id,user_enrole_active) values ('$last_inserted_mysql_id','$e','1')";
                        $container=mysql_query($add_to_enrole,$db_connect) or die ("cannot insert into user enrole");
        if($container)
  {
   $to = $b;
   $subject = "Confirmation from OnlineShopping to $a";
   $header = "OnlineShopping: Confirmation from OnlineShopping";
   $message = "Please click the link below to verify and activate your account. rn";
   $message .= "http://www.yourname.com/confirm.php?passkey=$com_code";

   $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

   if($sentmail)
            {
   echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
   }
   else
         {
    echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
   }
  }
```

i get error at first insert query while inserting data into the user table it dies there. Second problem is i am using local host as server so will it be able to send email using local host as a server

Comment: Replace `or die (mysql_error());` instead of `or die ("cannot execute query");` and checks the error

Comment: Although this doesn't resolve your problem, I would recommend you to use mysqli or PDO instead of the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: through mysql_error i have executed the query but i havent received email on my email address how can i fix it? is it happening because i am using localhost as a server?

Comment: echo your query and copy it check it in mysql

Comment: my insert query is working now i was able to fix the error.
but i am not receiving any email although my if($sentmail) is true and i am getting message that your confirmation link has been sent to your email address but when i havent received any email at in my inbox

Comment: You must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the ones you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_POST` data **never** goes directly in a query.

Comment: It's also terrifying that you're using the feeble MD5 hashing algorithm for storing important password data. There are [much better ways of doing this](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing).

Comment: @tadman sure i will try to avoid mysql_query in future. but can u point out whats the problem with my mail function why isnt it sending email on specified address?